# SQLALCHEMY or_ list comprehension

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use list comprehension with or_. I already found a post that showed how to do it with only checking one column, but I'm unsure how to check two columns simultaneously with a list. I tried something like this:

`q = q.filter(or_((model.column.contains(word), model.column2.contains(word))for word in search))`

This gives me a bad request though. Any advice on how to search simultaneously  using a list would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand you need to *unpack* the conditions into positional arguments of [`or_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_):

```
columns = [model.column, model.column2]
conditions = [column.contains(word) for word in search for column in columns]
q = q.filter(or_(*conditions))
```

Assuming you want to "or" every contains for every word and for all given columns.

Comment: conditions can be a generator: `or_(column.contains(word) for word in search for column in columns)`